# Batch File to compare value in the first line in each of the 2 different txt files

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 files (say A.txt abd B.txt) having a numeric value in the first line of each (say "8" in A.txt and "9" in B.txt).

I have to compare the value at the first line only between the 2 files and based upon whether numeric value in A.txt is greater than B.txt or not, have to call another batch file.

Could anyone please help me in achieving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to set a variable to a line in a text file is to use `set /P` with a redirect.

```perl
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "a=" <"A.txt"
set /P "b=" <"B.txt"

if %a% gtr %b% call anotherbatchfile.bat
goto :EOF
```

If it wasn't the first line you wanted to set, but, say, the 5th, you'd just use several `set /P` commands within the same redirection, something like this:

```perl
<"A.txt" (
    set /P "a="
    set /P "a="
    set /P "a="
    set /P "a="
    set /P "a="
)

rem # or...

<"A.txt" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,5) do set /P "a="
)
```

Or you could use `for /f` to read a text file.  `help for` in a console window for more info.  Just for giggles, I'll also demonstrate how to use `call` to define a function within a batch script.

```perl
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (a b) do call :setfirstline "%%I.txt" %%I

if %a% gtr %b% call anotherbatchfile.bat
goto :EOF

:setfirstline <txtfile> <var_to_return>
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~1") do (set "%~2=%%I" & goto :EOF)
```